# Extract value from JSON document returned by curl

Tags: curl, json

The command

```bash
curl "https://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host={18.205.6.240}"
```

returns the following JSON document:

```json
{"status":"success","description":"Data successfully received.","data":{"geo":{"host":"18.205.6.240","ip":"18.205.6.240","rdns":"ec2-18-205-6-240.compute-1.amazonaws.com","asn":14618,"isp":"AMAZON-AES","country_name":"United States","country_code":"US","region_name":"Virginia","region_code":"VA","city":"Ashburn","postal_code":"20149","continent_name":"North America","continent_code":"NA","latitude":39.0469,"longitude":-77.4903,"metro_code":511,"timezone":"America\/New_York","datetime":"2022-06-17 10:44:39"}}}
```

In this output, I need to extract the `country_name`. I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$ curl -s 'https://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host={18.205.6.240}' | jq -r '.data.geo.country_name'
United States
```

The `jq` expression `.data.geo.country_name` extracts the given item in the JSON document returned from the endpoint that you access with `curl`.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use the below version also:
Below is REST API output:

```json
{
  "error": "none",
  "message": "Success",
  "data": {
    "name": "Vishal Biradar",
    "userId": 1,
  }
}
```

Below is the script code that shows how we can read it.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
LOGIN_DATA=$(\
    curl -d "email=abcd@gmail.com&password=abcd123" \
    http://localhost:1234/login \
    | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['data']['name']"\
)
echo "LOGIN_DATA=$LOGIN_DATA"
```

Comment: print(json.load(sys.stdin)['access_token']) in case of python 3+. Great solution anyway

Comment: Apart from being about parsing out a specific part of some JSON document, this does not seem to be related to the problem at hand. You could have used the example document quoted in the question instead.

Comment: Might as well just use python in this case